# ASP.NET Core - can't get simple bearer token auth working

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, bearer-token

I am building an API with ASP.NET Core 2, and I am trying to get a simple auth example that uses a Bearer token to work.

First, here is my Startup code...

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "mydomain.com",
                    ValidAudience = "mydomain.com",
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("THESECRETKEY THESECRETKEY THESECRETKEY THESECRETKEY"))
                };
            });

        // goes last
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler();
        }

        app.UseStatusCodePages();

        // goes last
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Then I have an Auth controller, that returns the token...

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("RequestToken")]
    public IActionResult RequestToken([FromBody] TokenRequest request)
    {
        if (request.Username == "theuser" && request.Password == "thepassword")
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, request.Username)
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("THESECRETKEY THESECRETKEY THESECRETKEY THESECRETKEY"));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "mydomain.com",
                audience: "mydomain.com",
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                signingCredentials: creds);

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)
            });
        }

        return BadRequest("Could not verify username and password");
    }
}

public class TokenRequest
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

So in Postman you can see I get a token back...

[image]

And then I try GET from a Values controller...

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

If I add the [Anonymous] attribute, it works fine.  However, when it requires authorization, I get a 401...

[image]

Comment: By the looks of it, you need to add `app.UseAuthentication();` to the `Configure` method in the `StartUp` class, before the `app.UseMvc();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't referenced the Authentication middleware in your `Startup.cs`
You can reference it by adding `app.UseAuthentication();` preferably just before the `app.UseMvc();`

Here's how your `Startup.cs`'s `Configure` method should look like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler();
    }

    app.UseStatusCodePages();


    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

You can read more into middleware [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware) and more into authorization with ASP.NET Core [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

You should also look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) for everything else about ASP.NET Core